# How to insert many rows at once in many to many table with one fix value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have a many to many table, with ID1 and ID2. I want to insert many rows at once, where ID1 is always the same value, but I have many ID2 values to insert.

I was thinking if it is possible to use something like that:

```
insert into MyTable (ID1, ID2) VALUES(1, select ID from AnotherTable where ID IN(1, 2, 3));
```

Where the select could be rows from a table or a variable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into MyTable (ID1, ID2) 
    select 1, ID
    from AnotherTable
    where ID in (1, 2, 3);
```

This will insert all matching rows from `AnotherTable`, along with a constant value for the first column.

Answer (score 1):

Please use below syntax to insert from another table,

```
insert into MyTable (ID1, ID2) (select 1, ID from AnotherTable where ID IN(1, 2, 3));
```